# replace nearest matching word using php preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

currently i am using php preg_replace to replace certain portion of string

```
12854827.12854827_IDS.0 12854827.12854827_892.0
12854827.12854827_IDS.0 12854827.12854827_892.0
```

here i required output is

```
12854827.IDS.0 12854827.892.0
12854827.IDS.0 12854827.892.0
```

but preg_replace produced output

```
12854827.892.0
12854827.892.0
```

php code that i used given below

```
preg_replace('/\..*_/', '.', $A)
```

how i solve above problem ?
&
how i replace nearest matching word using php preg_replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regular expression to capture everything between a dot character (`.`) and an underscore (`_`):

```
/\.([^_.]+)_/
```

Breakdown:

- `/` - starting delimiter

  - `\.` - match literal dot (`.`) character
  - `[^_.]` - character class that matches any character that's not a `.` or `_` one or more times
  - `_` - match literal underscore (`_`) character
- `/` - ending delimiter

The `preg_replace()` statement should look like:

```
preg_replace('/\.([^_.]+)_/', '.', $A);
```

Effectively, it says: "Replace everything between a `.` and `_` with a `.`".

Output:

```
12854827.IDS.0 12854827.892.0
12854827.IDS.0 12854827.892.0
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/104561)

Comment: why u use ([^_.]+) in regex

Comment: @lintocheeran: Are you sure you're seeing the latest version of this answer? I've already explained this in the answer. It is used to match everything between a `.` and `_`. [**See Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eW9rV6)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using digit replace you can use this one:

```
preg_replace('/\.\d+_/', '.', $A);
```